# iOS Firebase app not configured after calling FIRApp.configure()

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an iOS (Swift) app with the following code in the AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
  FIRApp.configure()
  FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true
  return true
}
```

The app crashes on the `persistenceEnabled = true` line, with exception `FIRAppNotConfigured`, and the message `"Failed to get default FIRDatabase instance. Must call FIRApp.configure() before using FIRDatabase."`

Obviously, I've called `FIRApp.configure()` immediately before this, so the suggested solution is incorrect. The log output even shows `"Configuring the default app"` when that is called.

What might the problem be, and how could I resolve it so I can use the FIRDatabase?

Answer (score 13):

Try:

```
override init() {
   // Firebase Init
   FIRApp.configure()
}
```